# Use variable in regexPrefix?

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
// Util function
function addFormatter(input, formatFn) {
  let oldValue = input.value;

  const handleInput = event => {
    const result = formatFn(input.value, oldValue, event);
    if (typeof result === 'string') {
      input.value = result;
    }

    oldValue = input.value;
  }

  handleInput();
  input.addEventListener("input", handleInput);
}

// Example implementation
// HOF returning regex prefix formatter
function regexPrefix(regex, prefix) {
  return (newValue, oldValue) => regex.test(newValue) ? newValue : (newValue ? oldValue : prefix);
}

// Apply formatter
const input = document.getElementById('user_login');
addFormatter(input, regexPrefix(/mysite-/, 'mysite-'));
```

I want to use this fiddle to work with a variable instead of text, this is the line:

```
addFormatter(input, regexPrefix(/mysite-/, 'mysite-'));
```

As you can see it only allows you to input text after `mysite-` which is how I want it to work. But I want to be able to use a variable where it says `mysite-`. Like this:

```
addFormatter(input, regexPrefix(/$sitetitle/, $sitetitle));
```

Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: That's JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: Wow sorry! I don't know what I thought of!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a regexp dynamically using the `RegExp()` constructor.

```
addFormatter(input, regexPrefix(new RegExp('^' + $sitetitle), $sitetitle));
```

Comment: I just realised I missed this detail: `addFormatter(input, regexPrefix(/^mysite-/, 'mysite-'));`. This `^` disabled the possibility to put any letters before the word `mysite` Is it possible to integrate this too?

Comment: Just use string concatenation. I've updated the answer.